# How to set up tasks.json for Visual Studio Code so that it can run .cpp files outside Developer command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-tasks

I've started using Visual Studio Code (version 1.83.1) few days ago, and I want to run C++ files by MSVC compiler without using "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022" every time. And I want to know how can I modify tasks.json file for this purpose, because it's the only way I know to do it.

I used the instructions from here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_run-vs-code-outside-the-developer-command-prompt

Tried every variant from here:

[How to configure the VS Code shell like the developer command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60531123/how-to-configure-the-vs-code-shell-like-the-developer-command-prompt/60546712#60546712)

Nothing helps, task file works without errors, but when I try to run .cpp file it gives an error:

```
cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.
```

My VsDevCmd.bat file is placed where it should be:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools
And when I run that Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 manually everything works fine, but if I try to do it using tasks.json it fails.

At the moment my tasks.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "windows": {
    "options": {
      "shell": {
        "executable": "cmd.exe",
        "args": [
          "/C",
          // The path to VsDevCmd.bat depends on the version of Visual Studio you have installed.
          "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\"",
          "&&"
        ]
      }
    } 
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "process",
      "label": "cl.exe build active file",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "&", 
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/Fe:",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "${file}"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you already installed _Visual Studio 2022 Community_, why on Earth do you want to use _Visual Studio Code_ instead, which is less powerful and more complicated to configure?

Comment: @prapin, it's because of code analyzer not working for C++20 modules properly. So I can't see errors before compiling and almost all my code has pure black font color. I also cannot see most of variables while debugging modules - this was the last straw.
VS Code at least has much better syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Dadunddd.aD This is a valid reason indeed. I knew that C++20 modules are still very buggy on Visual Studio, but I didn't know this bug.